# Unable to upgrade cifs-utils package

Tags: package-management, dpkg, cifs

I'm trying to upgrade `cifs-utils` package on Ubuntu 18.04, but getting the
following error.

```
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/cifs-utils_2%3a6.8-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb <br>
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have Googled the error and tried the following to no avail.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Tried to force an overwrite `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite`, but get the following:

```
dpkg: error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/cifs-utils_2%3a6.8-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
(--install): unable to install (supposed) new info file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postinst': Structure needs cleaning
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/cifs-utils_2%3a6.8-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue please?

Comment: "*Structure needs cleaning*" is not an overwriting problem. It's not any kind of apt or dpkg problem. It's a filesystem problem. Unmount and fsck the partition.

Comment: Thanks. After I force unmount the partition and run a fsck against my main filesystem /dev/sda2 I get the following error.

fsck.ext2: No such file or directory /dev/sda2

I'm not great with Linux so most my knowledge comes from 'how to' pages after a Google search. I come across this command which is meant to run a fsck on boot (sudo touch /forcefsck), but didn't fix my cifs package issue.

Comment: Are you saying that after a successfully-completed fsck (with a message telling you about what was fixed), you still have a "structure needs cleaning" error?

Comment: I'm saying I am unable to run an fsck. After unmount I get an error - fsck.ext2: No such file or directory /dev/sda2

Comment: Well, that's expected if you unmounted your root filesystem. fsck rule #1: You can't fsck the filesystem that is currently booted. Most folks boot a LiveUSB (installer), click into the "Try Ubuntu" environment, and fsck their (unmounted) hard drive from there.

Comment: I've download an ISO from Ubuntu server, but I don't have the "Try Ubuntu" option available. I tried to press CTRL ALT T to get to a terminal window, but it does not work via VMWare Remote Console. I also booted into recovery mode to run a fsck from there, but I get another error - /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcs: no such file or directory fsck from util-linux 2.31.1. Any ideas please, I'm stuck?

Comment: Oh, you did not mention Ubuntu Server. The "Try Ubuntu" environment is on the Desktop installer. You found other ways to trigger fsck, so that's not important anymore. Your "rcS" problem looks like a bug in that script. If you have the skill, you can simply comment out that line. If not, then use [forcefsck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231972/how-to-check-disks-at-startup-alternative-to-chkdsk-c-f-on-windows) and reboot to trigger.

Comment: This fix sorted it in the end - https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/0...ilesystem.html . Thanks for the assistance. All a learning curve for my Linux knowledge.